# Remove/Delete TestSuite from TFS2012 programmatically with API

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I am using the API from TFS2012 to automatically create Testsuites in our tfs. This is all going great. But I want to remove all the TestSuites from tfs before adding them through the API.

Does anyone know if the API provides this functionality.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following, where `tfsUri` is the location of the collection, and `tfsProjectName` is the name of the project:

```
var tfsTeamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri);
var tfsTestManagementService = tfsTeamProjectCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
var tfsTestManagementTeamProject = tfsTestManagementService.GetTeamProject(tfsProjectName);
var tfsTestPlans = tfsTestManagementTeamProject.TestPlans.Query("SELECT * FROM TestPlan");
foreach (var tfsTestPlan in tfsTestPlans)
{
    tfsTestPlan.Delete(DeleteAction.ForceDeletion);
}
```